# Curious page top questions

Tags: discussion, user-interface

When you go to

https://math.stackexchange.com/

You get to a page that somehow list the Top Questions

- how is decided which questions are on this page?

Also from the normal question site

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions there is no link to the top questions page.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the front page of the site. The set of questions there is determined by the selectors (tabs) to the right - active, featured and so on. Hovering over the tab name will show the criteria used by the tab. The default tab is *active*, which lists questions by most recent activity such as answers and edits.

Perhaps calling this view "top" is a bit misleading. This word makes more sense on StackOverflow, where the default tab works differently. But in a very weak sense, the questions on the front page are "top scoring questions" - namely, the questions scored $<-3$ do not appear there.

As for a link to the top questions page, there is one: it is the word **Mathematics** set in very large font, in all caps.